# BigqueryIO schema from table row

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a PCollection of TableRow with tablename and schema in the table row as below

[image]

I need to insert col1,col2 and col3 value into Table with Schema in the row mentioned using
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()

We could use lambda to access the table name from row as below
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(tablerow->tablerow.get("Table").toString())
but how could we access the schema from the table row using BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().withSchema()

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [DynamicDestination](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) to select for each element a table Name and a schema to apply.

To decompose the code example of the documentation

```
events.apply(BigQueryIO.<UserEvent>write()
  .to(new DynamicDestinations<UserEvent, String>() {
// Here you extract the "key" value for the selection of schema and table. 
// If you need the values of the 2 first column, you can create your own structure
// Example: <schema>|<table>
        public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<UserEvent> element) {
          return element.getValue().getUserId();
        }
// Here return the Table destination (dataset and table) according to the "Key"
// If you have the value in your key, you can do key.split("|")[1], according to my previous example
        public TableDestination getTable(String user) {
          return new TableDestination(tableForUser(user), "Table for user " + user);
        }
//Same for the schema here.
        public TableSchema getSchema(String user) {
          return tableSchemaForUser(user);
        }
      })
```